# Using anonymous function rather than looping for summing up values in cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have a matrix called data. It contains 3 columns, company name, company value & company currency, bit like below.

```
  Name      Value      Currency
  ABC       10         USD
  MNO       5          JPY
  PLM       3          USD
  NJK       7          EUR
```

I need to sum the total value for each currency so my answer would look like below,

```
 Currency    Value
 EUR         7
 JPY         5
 USD         13
```

I know I can do this using a loop but is it possible using an anonymous function and if so how?

**Update - Extra information as original post lacked information**

Below is my solution, which works. However I have seen people use cellFun or anonymous functions and fell like there is a more efficient way (and would to like alternative way) for problems of this nature

```
val     = cell2mat(data(:, 2));              % double - value
sedols  = data(:, [1 3]);                   % cell - name (1st column) and currency (2nd column)

ccy     = unique(sedols(:, 2));
fx_exp  = zeros(length(ccy(:, 1)), 1);

for n = 1 : length(ccy(:, 1))
    index           = strmatch(ccy(n, 1), sedols(:, 2));
    fx_exp(n, 1)    = sum(val(index));
end
```

Comment: Your matrix is a cell array or a table? please define the variable in an executable manner.

Comment: Please list your attempt at solving this as a loop, so we have a better idea what you are doing. See [mcve]

Comment: and what is `data`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `cellfun` or `arrayfun` **is not** more efficient than a simple loop. To take advantage of vectorization you need to work with pure *double arrays*.

Assuming your data is stored in a cell array, [**`unique`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) combined with [**`accumarray`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is the way to go:

```
data = {
    'ABC'   10  'USD'
    'MNO'   5   'JPY'
    'PLM'   3   'USD'
    'NJK'   7   'EUR' };

[a,b,subs] = unique(data(:,3))
vals = [data{:,2}];
currsum = accumarray(subs,vals)
out = [data(b,3) num2cell(currsum)]
```

---

```
out = 

'EUR'    [ 7]
'JPY'    [ 5]
'USD'    [13]
```